# How to get all elements from XML through XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I need to get all XML elements present in a given file through XQuery.
For eg:

```
<xml>
   <a>attr="one"
       <b>attr2="in-a"
           <c>leaf</c>
       </b>
   </a>
</xml>
```

the output should return the following:

```
<xml>,<a>,<b>,<c>
```

and if possible in hierarchical manner. And I need to use only XQuery.

Any help appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, where `/test.xml` contains the document:

```
fn:string-join(fn:doc('/test.xml')//*/(concat(name(.), ' > ')))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That was quick :)